# How to resolve "Your Bitbucket token is no longer valid. Please re-authenticate." in Visual Studio App Center without disconnecting?

Tags: azure, bitbucket, visual-studio-app-center

**Problem**
I am using Azure App Center connected to BitBucket to build an app. The user who originally setup the BitBucket connection is no longer available. Clicking "Reconnect" fails. The only other option I see is disconnect the BitBucket Repo, but that would remove the build configuration and history completely.

Has anyone experienced this before and has a solution to reconnect?

**What I've tried**
Re-enabled the old user account, gave it permissions again to BitBucket, logged into App Center with that old account, and clicked Reconnect. This didn't change anything.

[image: Screenshot from Azure App Center]

[image]

Comment: Any solution for this one?

Comment: @BRass yes, you have to contact support. I've just added the answer below with the details you need to send to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you have to contact App Center support to resolve this issue.

Ask them to "transfer the repository ownership to a different account". This was the wording they used at least.

You must provide them:

- An email address with an App Center account
- The URL for the App Center repository that you want to transfer.

Thankfully their support team was helpful in performing the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known incident and the App Center engineering team is actively working to resolve the issue.

You can also follow the status here:

https://status.appcenter.ms/incidents/4q9q7hdbsdk6

Comment: That issue appears to be an intermittent status issue as of March 20 2023 (yesterday at time of writing). I don't think that was the case when I posted this problem. I contacted App Centre support and will post the answer here.